# Create NSLayoutConstraint inside custom tableView cell

Tags: swift, height, tableview, nslayoutconstraint

I'm working in function which is located in custom **tableViewCell**.swift-file

In this cell (aka row) I've 3 constraints: for **top**, **bottom** and its **height**. I need to connect row's contentView to row top, bottom and then its height to calculated height (which calculates by creating this row interface).

I know the format of creating NSLayoutConstraint but I **dont know how to set second view as 'its row height'.**

Had a try like this:

```
topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: UIView(), attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 31)
```

But got an EXC_BAD_ADRESS on `self.contentView.addConstraint()`